# Does the Facebook Deauthorize Callback execute when a user's access token expires?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps, facebook-access-token

Does the [Facebook Deauthorize Callback](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.2) fire off when a user's access token has been invalidated because the user changed their password or their token expired after 60 days?

An expiration is easy enough to plan for, but a password change can happen at any time.  Is there an alternative callback available for when a user changes their password?

Comment: So far, my findings appear to be "no" for all questions, but perhaps I missed something?

Comment: No the callback will not fire if they change their password. And there is no callback if they do. You will get an error when you do an api call with an access token that was created before they changed their password